# Unable to sell DWEKAM

Tags: stocks, india, stock-exchanges, bse-india

I am trying to exit DWEKAM shares position.  I tried the AMO option before market starts but still my 20000 shares are not sold. Daily I am going in huge loss. Any pointer on this will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DWEKAM shares position. I tried the AMO option before market starts but still my 20000 shares are not sold

For the shares to be sold, there has to be a buyer. If you see positions on 21st August, there are zero buyers. Around 21 lacs sellers. So the stock looks illiquid for now. Generally in such situations, there may be a take over / merger and you maybe able to see the stock else the company would go bankrupt and shares worthless.

Comment: @Kiran234567 You win some, you loose some. You learn from the processes.